# Php Get values from specific tags in a string

Tags: php, xml, regex, search

I have a string

```
$string= '<Label>1</Label><Value>1</Value><Label>2</Label><Value>2</Value><Label>3</Label><Value>3</Value><Label>4</Label><Value>4</Value><Label>5</Label><Value>5</Value>';
```

I need to separate the Label and Value tag values into two separate arrays. I tried to use the following function

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) 
{
    $pattern = "/<$tagname>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    return $matches;
}
```

I created another function to make it two separate arrays

```
function formatChoices($choices)
{
    $return['label'] = $this->getTextBetweenTags($choices, "Label");
    $return['value'] = $this->getTextBetweenTags($choices, "Value");

    return $return;
}
```

But it returns the following

```
Array([label] => Array(
        [0] => 1</Label><Value>1</Value><Label>2</Label><Value>2</Value><Label>3</Label><Value>3</Value><Label>4</Label><Value>4</Value><Label>5
        [1] => 7
    )

[value] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1</Value><Label>2</Label><Value>2</Value><Label>3</Label><Value>3</Value><Label>4</Label><Value>4</Value><Label>5</Label><Value>5
        [1] => 23))
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Use an XML parser for this. Regular expressions are not the right tool for the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?php
$string= '<Label>1</Label><Value>1</Value><Label>2</Label><Value>2</Value><Label>3</Label><Value>3</Value><Label>4</Label><Value>4</Value><Label>5</Label><Value>5</Value>';
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string('<data>'.$string.'</data>')),1);
print_r($array);
?>
```

Comment: WTF that bunch of functions ??? It is really bad practice - if it is XML or XML Data, SimpleXML is enough

Comment: @SergeS: We have to use JSON functions to ensure there are no exotic values that would cause problems when unserializing.

Comment: In all cases this is not the problem, problem is not used simpleXML ( because of bad design )

Comment: @SergeS Do you have any other better solution?

Comment: Solution is to use SimpleXML - it can be used as array in many cases and in this answer simplexml is used

Comment: I think in performance questions the regex variants would be faster, than loading a complete xml dom manipulation libary for such an easy task.

Answer (score 1):

The inside of tags cannot have '<' and '>' character, so change it this way

```
$pattern = "/<$tagname>([^<>]*)<\/$tagname>/";
```

PS For XML Manipulation it is better to use SimpleXML or DOM or ...

Comment: This patter returns the following Array
(
    [label] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 7
        )

    [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 23
        )

)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the point it tries to match as match as possible. (The point is greedy.)

**Edit**: This should work:

```
$pattern = "/<$tagname>(.*?)<\/$tagname>/";
```